# How do I connect the Spinner ids from the kivy file with the data that I provide from my products database?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, spinner

How do I connect my ids to the python code considering I want to load the string from self.listcode variable into the values of the spinner, I already use self. ids. and I don't get anything from the KV file. Thanks in advance for ur help. One of the errors popping out is  the one  below:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__
```

I think if I'm not wrong that it has to do with that Screen doesn't having the possibility to access ids

#### KIVY FILE###

```
<WindowManager>:
    FirstWindow:
    
    
    SecondWindow:



<FirstWindow>:
    name: "menu"
    
    canvas.before:    
        Color:
            rgba: (242/255, 202/255, 5/255, 1)        
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [55]
    
    
    Image: 
        source: 'Logoapp.png'
   

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: 50, 50    
        Button:
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":.5, "top":.2}
            pos:100, 100
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            text: "Cotizar"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (23/255,152/255,216/255,0.71)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius:[55]

            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "cotiza"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "cotiza"
    FloatLayout:
        CodigoSpin:
            id: "Cod_prod"
            pos: 20, 100
            Label:
                text: "Descripcion"
                pos: 20, 35
        CodigoSpin:
            id: "Cod_prod2"
            pos: 20, 200
            Label:
                text: "Descripcion"
                pos: 20, 130
            
        CodigoSpin:
            id: "Cod_prod3"
            pos: 20, 300  
            Label:
                text: "Descripcion"
                pos: 20, 235

<CodigoSpin@Spinner>:
    
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 44
    text: "CodigoSpin"
```

### Main Program

```
from types import new_class
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner, SpinnerOption
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, RoundedRectangle
import sqlite3

Window.size = (250, 500 ) #Changed the size of the screen to fit my phone

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class FirstWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
   pass
    

class SecondWindow(Screen, Widget):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            #Create de Database connection
            conn = sqlite3.connect("inventingt.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.execute("""SELECT Codigo FROM masterinv """)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()

            #Create the variable listcode of objects from the database
            self.listcode = [str(t[0]) for t in rows] 

            #This method will initialize the values on the Spinner 

            self.inicializarvalores()
        


    def inicializarvalores(self):
        self.ids.Cod_prod.values = self.listcode
        
        


class WindowManager(ScreenManager, Widget):
    
    pass
            

class Buendes(App):
    def build(self):
        #Inicializamos el screen manager para inicializar las paginas
        
        self.window = WindowManager()
        #add widgets to window
        
          
    
        
        #Agregamos el boton de inicializar la aplicacion

        #Conectamos una base de datos
        
        
        
        return self.window


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Buendes().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to connect your widgets which are created in .kv file to .py file is:

- Give `id` to your widget. ( ✓ You did it as `Cod_prod` )
- in .kv file, top of your class (under `<SecondWindow>:`), type this: `Cod_prod:Cod_prod` ( ☓ )
- Import this : `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty` ( ☓ )
- Now under `class SecondWindow`(in .py file), identify your object: `Cod_prod = ObjectProperty()`

Now you can access your widget which is created in .kv file with:

```
def inicializarvalores(self):
    self.Cod_prod.values = self.listcode
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also a way to do it, but in my case, it was simple as initializing the listcode variable in the class and then using root.listcode in the values section of the spinner in the kv file, and then in order to get ids properly the error I was committing is that ids don't need "" or ' '. So if someone doesn´t know this, don't put this in order to kivy build the ids dictionary properly.

Comment: Yes its true i didn't realised that and tried to fix your problem. I'm glad you solved it. For help other users which have this problem, it's good to have both solutions shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand the situation on Spinner and Screen connection. I had same problem. Also tried both solutions but couldn't get the solution.
I couldn't assign values to Spinner on root class inherited Screen.

What I tried:

1. On py file: self.ids.spinnerid.values = list -> not working. But py connected the spinner.
2. On kv file: Spinner: values: root.list -> not working.
3. Try to ListProperty, ObjectProperty... -> not working.

I turned around the problem using *values: app.list* on kv file and define the list on App class.